# Trellis Generator

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've been tasked with writing a simple trellis generator. The user is prompted with entering the height and width of the desired trellis, and gets a printed result of a trellis with the entered dimensions. I'm looking for code compact improvements, as I was told to use as little code as possible to generate the trellis.

**script.py**

```
height = input("Enter EVEN height of trellis: ")
width = input("Enter EVEN width of trellis: ")

print(("--" * width) + "--" )
for i in range(height):
    print("|" + ("/\\" * width) + "|")
    print("|" + ("\\/" * width) + "|")
print(("--" * width) + "--")
```

Comment: Is it a "hard" requirement to support Python 2? Or can you upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't get the `"Enter EVEN height of trellis: "` part.

```
Enter EVEN height of trellis: 3
Enter EVEN width of trellis: 3
--------
|/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/|
|/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/|
--------
```

But let's continue.

**Assumptions:**

1. Shorten means lessen the number of characters
2. Neatness of the code matters

Ways to shorten the code:

- Change `height` to `h` and `width` to `w`
- Convert `("--" * w) + "--"` to `"--" * (w+1)`
- Join the two inputs using `raw_input` and `map`:
  `h, w = map(int, raw_input("Enter EVEN 'height width' of trellis: ").split())`
- Join the two `print` statements in the for loop:
      `print ("|" + "/\\" * w + "|") + "\n" + ("|" + "\\/" * w + "|")`

If neatness doesn't matter, remove all spaces and newlines in the code.

My improved version:

```
h, w = map(int, raw_input("Enter EVEN 'height width' of trellis: ").split())

print "--" * (w+1)

for i in range(h):
    print ("|" + "/\\" * w + "|") + "\n" + ("|" + "\\/" * w + "|")

print "--" * (w+1)
```

Customize the code as you wish!

That's all I can think about. Good luck!

**Edit:**
If python 3.x is allowed:

```py
h, w = map(int, input("Enter EVEN 'height width' of trellis: ").split())
print('--' * (w+1), *(("|" + "/\\" * w + "|") + '\n' + ("|" + "\\/" * w + "|") for _ in range(h)), '--' * (w+1), sep='\n')
```

I hope it works. I haven't checked it :D

Comment: `raw_input` should be avoided since it isn't compatible with Python 3. You can do an equivalent operation that will be compatible with both.

Comment: I also think that the gymnastics you've done with `map` are on the whole counterproductive; even if you want to "code golf" this thing there are saner ways.

Comment: Furthermore, your input isn't equivalent. You're asking the user to input a tuple, instead of inputting the height and width individually.

Comment: @David White wanted to make the code as small as possible. And of course, I added `Customize the code as you wish!` :D

Comment: `raw_input should be avoided since it isn't compatible with Python 3.` I thought about it first too, but the question tag says `python 2.x`

Answer (score 5):

Since we're playing code golf, this is passable - but please don't do it in production. It's too confusing. I've taken the liberty of using Python 3 despite the question being tagged for 2; if you really need it for 2 I can provide an alternative (that will be longer).

```
h, w = (int(input(f'Enter EVEN {dim} of trellis: ')) for dim in ('height', 'width'))
arrow = r'\/'
print('{horz}\n{rows}{horz}'.format(horz='--'*(w + 1),
    rows=f'|{arrow[::-1] * w}|\n|{arrow * w}|\n' * h))
```